# Procrustes superimposition and sliding in integrated structures

Tags: procrustes-analysis

Assume I have the following structure.

[image]

Black dots represent semilandmarks to be slid, and red dots are "anatomical", or "fixed", landmarks. They are both dependent on each other, so that the position of the red dots depends on the position of the black dots. Would running a procrustes analysis with sliding on this sort of data (where the black dots are slid and the red are not) appropriate?

My concern is that is that if the black dots are slid, then they might become "detached" from the red dots, and their relationship would be violated.

A real world example would be this [supplementary material from a study](http://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/suppl/2013/10/15/1302653110.DCSupplemental/pnas.201302653SI.pdf?targetid=nameddest%3DSF3) [PDF]. They place anatomical landmarks on teeth, which are the dots within the dots making up the outline of the tooth(equivalent to the red dots in my example), and slide the semilandmarks that make up the outline of the tooth (the black dots in my figure). Because the anatomical landmarks and semilandmarks are basically integrated, I wonder whether it's appropriate.